# Audio crackling and xruns in firefox only

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, firefox, jack

I have an issue when using firefox (only seems to happen in firefox, chromium is not affected). When playing any audio in firefox, whether music or video, if in full screen (or theater mode on youtube, happens then too), audio crackles and pops.

I'm using JACK as I have a USB sound card with direct inputs for instruments, and I do record/practice using it and need the lower latency, however this occurs whether JACK is running and pulseaudio is bridged, or whether JACK is off and pulseaudio has control, and was happening before I installed JACK. I suspect it is an issue with pulseaudio, but I'm not sure how to check and what else to try.

I also noticed, while this bug is occuring, the system stutters a little bit (video playback slightly hangs) and a lot of xruns are occuring.

USB card used is a Scarlett Solo, other audio inputs on the system are not used (video card and onboard I mean). Using linux mint 20.1, with a low latency kernel. So far I've tried changing the sample rate and buffer size/period to try and find a working combination, no success. I've also added tsched=0 to /etc/pulseaudio/default.pa, no effect.

Comment: Does `sudo dmesg` or your system log have anything at the time that happens? If it is only in full screen mode though, I'd try [to disable graphic acceleration in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1075185) and see what happens.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding! Looking through dmesg, just after a whole bunch of xruns occur, `retire_capture_urb: 10913 callbacks suppressed` appears. The number seems to be random. 

I have tried with both graphics acceleration on and off, it is the same effect. Strangely, I tried to install an older version of Firefox (ESR release) and this does not occur at all, which is very odd. Like, not even a bit of crackling or xruns over many hours of continuous playback.

Comment: Try setting media.webspeech.synth.enabled to false in about:config.